# Is there a way to detect when a standard iPhone View Controller push/pop animation has completed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For custom animations in my app, I can use the **setAnimationDidStopSelector:** method to respond to the event that an animation has finished.  Is there a similar kind of mechanism for detecting that the animation has finished for a standard View Controller animation transition for pushes and pops?

```
(i.e. [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try to overide the method:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

This method will be called after your view appeared

In the interface comment for the code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;    // Called when the view is about to made visible. Default does nothing

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;     // Called when the view has been fully transitioned onto the screen. Default does nothing
```

So I think that if you override the viewDidAppear and put your logic here, the code will be executed exactly after the transition finished

More in [viewWillAppear](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16) and [viewDidAppear](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW17)

Comment: Yeah, `viewDidAppear:` will be called when your view is done animating being shown and `viewDidDisappear:` when it's done animating showing another view controller.